# Exception occurred during parquet saving - SparkException: Task not serializable - NotSerializableException - object not serializable

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

The DiagnosticEvent class is an Avro generating class and it's having serialVersionUID as well.

```
20/01/05 09:56:09 ERROR nodeStatsConfigDriven.NodeStatsKafkaProcessor: DiagnosticEvent Exception occurred during parquet saving
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2289)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2063)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1327)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply$mcZ$sp(RDD.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply(RDD.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply(RDD.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.isEmpty(RDD.scala:1461)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.isEmpty(JavaRDDLike.scala:544)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.isEmpty(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at Spark2ParquetEngine.nodeStatsConfigDriven.NodeStatsKafkaProcessor.processSubRecordList(NodeStatsKafkaProcessor.java:463)
    at Spark2ParquetEngine.nodeStatsConfigDriven.NodeStatsKafkaProcessor.access$100(NodeStatsKafkaProcessor.java:42)
    at Spark2ParquetEngine.nodeStatsConfigDriven.NodeStatsKafkaProcessor$4.call(NodeStatsKafkaProcessor.java:252)
    at Spark2ParquetEngine.nodeStatsConfigDriven.NodeStatsKafkaProcessor$4.call(NodeStatsKafkaProcessor.java:273)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.servicenow.bigdata.schema.nodeStats.DiagnosticEvent
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.servicenow.bigdata.schema.nodeStats.DiagnosticEvent, value: {"schema_version": 2, etc...})
    - writeObject data (class: java.util.ArrayList)
    - object (class java.util.ArrayList, [{"schema_version": 2, etc...}])
    - writeObject data (class: java.util.HashMap)
    - object (class java.util.HashMap, {d12e3671478a0602f82a17c94c88155a=[{"schema_version": 2, etc}]
```

I've searched for this issue and tried in all the possible ways as mentioned in the posts. But, could not able to resolve the issue in my streaming application.
Please help in fixing this issue in streaming application while saving the data.

Code::

The exception is point to  nodeStats.foreachRDD

```
for(ChildNodeConfig childNodeConfig : xmlStatsConfig.getChildNodesList().getChildNodes()){
    if(childNodeConfig.isUseStatefulCacheFilter() &&  statefulFiltersMap.containsKey(childNodeConfig.getNodeFilterConfig().getName())){
        //logger.info("Applying stateful filter : "+childNodeConfig.getNodeFilterConfig().getName());
        JavaPairDStream<Void, Node>  nodeStats  = statefulFiltersMap.get(childNodeConfig.getNodeFilterConfig().getName()).applyStatefulFilter(nodeStats,intialStatefulRDDs.get(childNodeConfig.getNodeFilterConfig().getName()),hiveContext);

        nodeStats.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<Void,Node>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(JavaPairRDD<Void, Node> rdd) throws Exception {
                try {
                   
                    //Only Saving Diagnostic_Events - End */
                    logger.error("Filter the RDD into currentPartition");
                    // filter the RDD into two partitions
                    JavaPairRDD<Void, Node> currentPartition = rdd.filter(new Function<Tuple2<Void, Node>, Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public Boolean call(Tuple2<Void, Node> tuple) throws Exception {
                            if (tuple != null) {
                                Node nodeStats = tuple._2();
                                if (nodeStats != null && nodeStats.getCollectionTimestamp() != null) {
                                    long timestamp = nodeStats.getCollectionTimestamp()  * 1000;
                                    if (timestamp >= currHourTimestamp) {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    
                    if(processChildNodes || processAll) {
                        //logger.info("Processing Child Nodes");

                        for (ChildNodeConfig childNodeConfig : xmlStatsConfig.getChildNodesList().getChildNodes()) {
                            //logger.info("Testing: calling processSubRecordList for childNode-" + childNodeConfig.getName());
                            processSubRecordList(currentPartition, prevPartition, currentTime, properties,
                                    childNodeConfig.getName(), childNodeConfig.getNamespace(), childNodeConfig.getHdfsdir(), true);
                        }

                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    logger.error("Exception occurred during parquet saving", ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Exception occurred at this position on `!currentPartition.isEmpty()` check.

```
if (!currentPartition.isEmpty() && !currentPartition.partitions().isEmpty()) {
    logger.error("Saving the Child:: " + targetClass + " save current partition to " + tempPath);
    logger.info(targetClass + " save current partition to " + tempPath);
    currentPartition.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(tempPath + "/current",
            Void.class, clazz, AvroParquetOutputFormat.class, sparkJob.getConfiguration());
    logger.info(targetClass + " saved current partition to " + tempPath);
    // move the output parquet files into their respective partition
    UtilSpark2.moveTempParquetToDestHDFS(tempPath + "/current", hdfsOutputDir + currentDir, String.valueOf(currentTime), hdfs);
} else
    logger.info(targetClass + " Empty current partition.");
```

Comment: Will be hard to help without code. But obviously your driver fails to send an unserializable piece of code to your executors.

Comment: @baitmbarek  I've updated the details with code snippets, can you please help.